# passing python parameters into a string which will be used as a python parameter

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass python from a string in a web form with other inputs as optional parameters. I am using flask and all the values arrive at a python program as strings.
I would like to do something like this. I suspect the whole idea is impossible :)

Any ideas Stack ??

```
parameter_1 = "Foo"
parameter_2 = "Bar"
sql_string = 'Hello {parameter_1} this is  {parameter_2}; '
formatted_sql = f'''{sql_string}'''
print(sql_string)
print(formatted_sql)
```

Comment: While your question is about string templating (and I gave an answer below) the word SQL screams out to me. You should never build SQL queries by stuffing user-provided strings into templates as it will most probably lead to an SQL injection attack. Always use parametrized queries (how, depends on the DB driver).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.format()`:

```py
parameter_1 = "Foo"
parameter_2 = "Bar"
sql_string = 'Hello {p1} this is {p2}'
formatted = sql_string.format(p1=parameter_1, p2=parameter_2)
print(sql_string)
print(formatted)
```

This also allows `sql_string` to be used repeatedly, with different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Python is quite.. dynamic. You can use `locals()` to get a `dict` of the local variables. Then use `str.format()` to apply to the template (it will not be a f-string):

```
parameter_1 = "Foo"
parameter_2 = "Bar"
sql_string = 'Hello {parameter_1} this is {parameter_2}; '
formatted_sql = sql_string.format(**locals())
print(sql_string)
print(formatted_sql)
```

This will output:

```
Hello {parameter_1} this is {parameter_2};
Hello Foo this is Bar;
```

Now.. it WOULD be a better idea to just define the replacement variables directly as a `dict` such as:

```
tvars = { 'parameter_1': 'Foo', 'parameter_2': 'Bar' }
formatted_sql = sql_string.format(**tvars)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.